# How to find one INT and all INTs in SQL DB using BookshelfJS through an API

Tags: node.js, postgresql, bookshelf.js

I am creating an API that uses an ORM (bookshelf) to query postgresql. In this instance I want to be able to find all active tasks belonging to a user (parent_task = *) or all tasks belonging to a user with a specific parent task (parent_task = 1/2/3...). Currently, this endpoint works fine for tasks with a numeric parent, and I don't want to clutter my api by writing another nearly identical endpoint. So how can I use a wildcard with this same endpoint? Or should I just write a separate endpoint without the 'andWhere' query?

```
exports.assignedTasks = function(req, res){
  new User({user_id: req.params.id})
  .related('assignedTasks').query(function(qb) {
  qb.where('active', '<>', '0').andWhere('parent_task', '=', req.params.parent) }).fetch()
  .then(function(tasks){
    if (tasks){
      res.status(200).json(tasks)
    }
    else{
      res.status(404).json({'message' : 'Model not found'});
    }
  }).catch(function(err){
    res.status(500).json(err);
  })
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good practice to separate the database querying from the REST service. I suggest creating a `task-service.js` with a method like this:

```
exports.getTasks = function(user_id, parent_id) {
  // note the 'return' below.
  return new User({user_id: user_id})
      .related('assignedTasks')
      .query(function (qb) {
         qb = qb.where('active', '<>', '0');
         if (parent_id) {
           // if the function is called with one parameter or
           // second parameter is null, this will be skipped.
           qb.andWhere('parent_task', '=', parent_id);
         }
      }).fetch();
```

Then, in your `task-rest.js` (or something) you'd call this in the following manner:

```
exports.assignedTasks = function(req, res){
   taskService.getTasks(req.params.id, req.params.parent)
    .then(function(tasks) {
        if (tasks) {
           res.status(200).json(tasks);
        }
        // ...
    })
    .catch( /* ... */ );
}
```

Or with just one parameter (`getTasks(req.params.id)`).

Note that the 'assignedTasks' REST handler function will work even if `req.params.parent` is not defined.

Comment: Kalle, Thanks for answering the question so thoroughly and adding in best practices. I had gone ahead and just created another endpoint for the time being, but this looks like the solution I wanted.